# Need to define this array and figure out how to get first value php

Tags: php, string, var

I have a php var that `var_dump`'s this which is coming from a for loop query to the database.

```
string(19) "2021-09-14 15:23:27" string(19) "2021-09-17 09:59:28" string(19) "2021-09-23 10:29:33" string(19) "2021-09-24 16:07:50"
```

I first tried to convert them all to a single array with no luck.  when I covert it to an array using `explode`I get this which is multiple arrays.

```
array(1) { 
[0]=> string(19) "2021-09-14 15:23:27" } 
array(1) { 
[0]=> string(19) "2021-09-17 09:59:28" } 
array(1) { 
[0]=> string(19) "2021-09-23 10:29:33" } 
array(1) { 
[0]=> string(19) "2021-09-24 16:07:50" }
```

Ultimately what I need to do is get the strings values separately for different calculations.

for example: I would like to get the first string "2021-09-14 15:23:27" and use it for calculating time passed against another string such as "2021-09-24 16:07:50".

I know I'm missing something and it's probably very simple what is it?

here is the for loop code

```
$fd = new FormData("database_form");
$links = $another_dbForm->get_links('call_logs', $fd->get_field_struct('datetime'));
for($i=0; $i<count($links); $i++)
{
    $fd->set_ticket_id( $links[$i] );
    
    //get values for all logs and set var
    $logDate= $fd->get_field('datetime'); //gets all datetimes in strings
     var_dump($logDate);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant PHP code around those var_dumps?

Comment: added more code above